# How to build ascidoc PDF in IntelliJ with Maven on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, asciidoctor

My system setup is the following:

- IntelliJ 2017.2
- Maven 3.5.2
- Java 7
- Ubuntu 17.10

I have a project in IntelliJ where I want to use asciidoctor variant of asciidocs. I have created a adoc file, and now I want to create the PDF from that file.

I have tried:

```
mvn clean install -Pbuild-release-notes
```

But I cant find any PDF file.

Comment: What is your pom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the POM File (`pom.xml`) in this [asciidoctor-pdf-example](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-examples/tree/master/asciidoctor-pdf-example) project.

When you run:

```
mvn clean process-resources
```

*(the maven command depends from the `asciidoctor-maven-plugin` configuration in the POM File)*

You can run maven from the command line or from an IDE, you will get your PDF in `target/generated-docs`.